# Getting no data for Grafana 'Cluster Monitoring for Kubernetes' dashboard but gettting vallues for 'Node-exporter'

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, microk8s

I have installed microk8s (1.26, the latest) and have enabled the `observability` addon.

I get the following pods from `kube-prom-stack` up and running:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-15:~/percona-server-mongodb-operator$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
hostpath-provisioner-69cd9ff5b8-lljcs      1/1     Running   2 (97m ago)     3h48m
calico-node-sqxtg                          1/1     Running   1 (3h21m ago)   3h51m
calico-kube-controllers-79568db7f8-wqkcp   1/1     Running   1 (3h21m ago)   3h51m
coredns-6f5f9b5d74-9r5f6                   1/1     Running   1 (3h21m ago)   3h49m
metrics-server-7b8674ccdc-m2hc7            1/1     Running   0               3h11m
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-15:~/percona-server-mongodb-operator$ kubectl get pods -n observability
NAME                                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
kube-prom-stack-kube-prome-operator-79cbdd7979-5nqn2     1/1     Running   0             98m
kube-prom-stack-kube-state-metrics-5bf874b44d-cxsv9      1/1     Running   0             98m
kube-prom-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-5wfn9           1/1     Running   0             98m
kube-prom-stack-grafana-79bff66ffb-82jm9                 3/3     Running   0             98m
alertmanager-kube-prom-stack-kube-prome-alertmanager-0   2/2     Running   1 (97m ago)   97m
tempo-0                                                  2/2     Running   0             97m
prometheus-kube-prom-stack-kube-prome-prometheus-0       2/2     Running   0             97m
loki-promtail-ckvkt                                      1/1     Running   0             97m
loki-0                                                   1/1     Running   0             97m
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-15:~/percona-server-mongodb-operator$
```

I imported Grafana's [Cluster Monitoring - ID 10000](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/10000-kubernetes-cluster-monitoring-via-prometheus/) dashboard and I am getting N/A for all fields.

One of the query it focuses on is: `sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{image!="",name=~"^k8s_.*",kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^.*$"}) by (pod_name)`

Note that [Node Exporter Full](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1860-node-exporter-full/) gives all node level metrics.

I got some results with memory:

query: `container_memory_working_set_bytes{image!="",name=~"^k8s_.*",kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^.*$"}`
[image]

But when I run: `container_memory_working_set_bytes{image!="",kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^.*$"}`, I get something. So maybe `name=~"^k8s_.*"` is problematic, not sure what it means and why

[image]

---

Though CPU stuff is blank:
[image]

How do I debug this or know what went wrong?

Comment: Can you see anything with query `container_memory_working_set_bytes` in Grafana's explorer?

Comment: @markalex got some data actually. see latest question after my edits

Comment: @markalex no data for cpu but got some date for memory once I tweaked some args. Any idea from where I can study these function calls and its docs. Maybe then I can correct it

Comment: `name=~"^k8s_.*"` means that the label `name` must start with `k8s_`. I don't know why your panels contain this assumption in their queries. Look into description of the dashboard.